# How to deep copy an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I found this snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182429/how-make-deep-copy-clone-in-entity-framework-4):

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(this T obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return (T)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
```

Which says that we can do deep copy of all related objects through this thing.

I'm trying to do a copy like this:

```
db.Detach(myEntity); 
myEntity.EntityKEy = null;
Entity newEntity = new Entity();
newEntity = DeepClone<Entity>(Entity);
db.Entities.AddObject(newEntity);
db.SaveChanges();
```

IT works, but still does not copy any nested\related records. what do I do wrong here?

I have this structure Entity->ChildEntity ->ChildChildEntity
-> - one-to-many
so I assume when I copy entity it will also copy all child records.

**UPDATE:**
After suggestions, I did this:

```
Entity newEntity = new Entity();
Eneity Entity = db.Include("ChildEntity").Where(p=>p.Id==Id).Single();
newEntity = DeepClone<Entity>(Entity);
db.Detach(myEntity); 
myEntity.EntityKEy = null;
db.Entities.AddObject(newEntity);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Getting exception on AddObject line:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

Comment: Are you sure they're not null in the original object?

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo, yes, you are right, reference tables are empty if looking at the debugging :(. Why could this happen? this is how i Retrieve my original object: Entity original = db.Entities.Where(l=>l.ID == myId).Single();

Comment: Can you post the code for your entity?

Comment: Thats a nasty deep-copying way...not very performant...

Comment: @FelixK., what is a good way?

Comment: @user194076 Use the reflection to make the deep copy( The approach above is faster to implement but not faster ). You can find a approach here ( It's not complete, you need to improve the method to allow arrays and check references to avoid duplicated copies ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025890/is-there-a-much-better-way-to-create-deep-and-shallow-clones-in-c/8026574#8026574

Comment: @FelixK While it's true that a purely reflection-based copy performs better, the binary serialization copy is more reliable with less 'gotchas' involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important point is that you must load related entities and create deep clone **prior to detaching**. If you detach the entity all relations are silently removed because `Detach` method works only for single entity and entity graph cannot consists of both attached and detached entities. That is a reason why you need serialization instead of simply calling `Detach`.

Don't forget to turn off lazy loading otherwise your serialization will pull data for other navigation properties from database as well. Also remember that this deep copy will create new version of all entities in the graph so adding the root entity will add all related entities as well.

Answer (score 5):

The EntityKeys for all the child objects get cloned too, so you need to set each child's EntityKey to null before trying to add them with AddObject.

```
Entity oldEntity = db.Include("ChildEntity").Where(p => p.Id == Id).Single();
Entity newEntity = oldEntity.DeepClone(); // assuming you've put your DeepClone extension method in a static class so that it can be used as an extension
newEntity.EntityKey = null;
foreach(var childEntity in newEntity.ChildEntities)
{
    childEntity.EntityKey = null;
}
db.Entities.AddObject(newEntity);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: With this method you shouldn't even need the DeepClone.  Just load the entities from the Db and clear the all the primary keys.  Of course that may only apply to ef-codefirst

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't loaded the child entities before detaching the entity, they will not be serialized. Make sure all those navigational properties you want to deep clone are loaded before you detach the entity.

**Edit**

Eager load the navigational properties that must be serialized

```
var entity = db.Entities.Include("ChildEntity.ChildChildEntity")
        .Where(l=>l.ID == myId).Single();
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what happening.Any easy way to load children?

Answer (score 2):

You maybe should save context before you try to attach the entity one more time

```
Entity newEntity = new Entity();   
Eneity Entity = db.Include("ChildEntity").Where(p=>p.Id==Id).Single();   
newEntity = DeepClone<Entity>(Entity);   
db.Detach(myEntity);    
db.SaveChanges();  
myEntity.EntityKEy = null;   
db.Entities.AddObject(newEntity);   
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Check this question out. You have to detach all object you get for deep copy referenced in your object : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131779/unable-to-attach-a-detached-entity-an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists